# What is the longest single answer you've ever seen on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers

I was just reading through some random Stack Overflow questions and noticed that some people actually take the time to write some nice long answers. So I got to wondering what some of the longest (high quality) answers are.

I've gotten a few long answers to my own questions; [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189236/data-structures-for-message-passing-within-a-program/1191261#1191261), for example, had so much exciting insight that it led me to [asking (begging?) for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201361/3d-game-development-tips-especially-game-architecture) in a separate question.

**What are some of the longest, detailed, high-quality answers you've ever seen?** Is there a record for longest answer in SO? If so, I want to find it here!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran [a query on Stackql](http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/default.aspx?qid=651) and here are the top results:

- [Spanish accents in Sphinx searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058275/spanish-accents-in-sphinx-searches/2288529#2288529) (35480)
- [The .NET 2.0 SDK Programs - What does each tool do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362687/the-net-sdk-programs-what-does-each-tool-do/2176970#2176970) (33327)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381177/freetextbox-and-firefox-3-rendering-issue/381446#381446 (32673)
- [Matrix transforms; concepts and theory, are there any free resources for learning practically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016284/matrix-transforms-concepts-and-theory-are-there-any-free-resources-for-learning/1022743#1022743) (31946)

Though the first three are longer than the fourth, they all contain lists or big blocks of code that inflate the length of the post. The last one, however, is a legitimately long and detailed answer.

Comment: Do you still have the query? The link is broken. Would be nice to see updated results.

Answer (score 8):

- [ServerFault Wiki: How does Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/serverfault-wiki-how-does-subnetting-work/49836#49836)